# Linking error in protobuf with zeromq with c++

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am trying to use protobuf with zeromq in c++. I am getting below link error

```
/tmp/cco9X8QH.o: In function `google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInit(long*, void (*)())':
laserscan.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf14GoogleOnceInitEPlPFvvE[google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInit(long*, void (*)())]+0x4f): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl(long*, google::protobuf::Closure*)'
/tmp/cco9X8QH.o: In function `bool google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadPackedPrimitive<float, (google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::FieldType)2>(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>*)':
laserscan.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite19ReadPackedPrimitiveIfLNS2_9FieldTypeE2EEEbPNS0_2io16CodedInputStreamEPNS0_13RepeatedFieldIT_EE[bool google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadPackedPrimitive<float, (google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::FieldType)2>(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>*)]+0x85): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::BytesUntilLimit() const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here is my message

**scan.proto**

```
message Scan{
required float scan_time=1;        // time between scans [seconds]
repeated float ranges=2;        
}
```

here is my code where i am filling message and send.

**sender.cpp**

```
    Scan proto_msg;
proto_msg.set_scan_time(0.5);
proto_msg.add_ranges(1.0);

    std::string msg_str;
proto_msg.SerializeToString(&msg_str);

    zmq::message_t request (msg_str.size());
memcpy ((void *) request.data(), msg_str.c_str(),msg_str.size());
    socket.send (request);
```

**build command :**

```
g++ sender.cpp scan.pb.cc scan.pb.h -I /home/sender -l protobuf -l zmq
```

i had included `/usr/local/lib` in  `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `sudo ldconfig` .

I suspect this with either repeat field or with namespace of protobuf.

thank you.

Comment: Try to add "package scan_packages;" at start of proto file, if you guess it is problem of namespace.
Everything seems right. Are you sure it can find libraries? Try protobuf-lite also, will problem be same?

Comment: @Arkady i tried by adding package name but same result. protobuf-lite version is throwing more errors.

Comment: did you built protobuf? Could it be built wrong?

Comment: yes i built the code but no error while doing make, make check and make install

Comment: remove zmq and all other stuff, leave just protobuf, will there be this problem? If yes - you have problems with protobuf build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason why linking error. I have different version of `libprotobuf` libraraies installed. I did `ls | grep 'libproto'` in `/usr/lib/`  and `/usr/local/lib` result you can see in image. I manually deleted the files related to `libprotobuf` in `/usr/lib` and able to compile the code.

[image]